# OnChange get first td value if checkbox checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
Table   
 Checkbox Header1  Header2 Header 3
    x        foo      foo     foo
    o        foo      foo     foo
    o        foo      foo     foo
endTable

<select>
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
<select>
```

Checkbox id are dynamically added, "worksmart-checkbox" + count eg. "worksmart-checkbox1"

```
<table class="table table-responsive table-striped table-condensed">
    <tr>
        <th>
            Select
        </th>
        <th hidden>Value</th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Firstname)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Lastname)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Address)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Postcode)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CaseReference)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DateOfBirth)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SpouseFirstname)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SpouseLastname)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SpouseAddress)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SpousePostcode)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="@item.ElementID" />
            </td>
            <td hidden>@item.ApplicantID</td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Firstname)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Lastname)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Address)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Postcode)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CaseReference)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DateOfBirth)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SpouseFirstname)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SpouseLastname)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SpouseAddress)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SpousePostcode)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.ApplicantID })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

I am trying to get the value of the `"hidden"` `td` in the table on the row where the checkbox is checked. There are many checkboxes, however if one is checked all the rest are disabled.

I want to access the hidden td of the checked checkbox in the onChange method in a selet tag which sits outside the table.

```
$('#worksmart-select').on("change", function () {
       // get first td val
    });
```

Comment: Do you consider `select` as your first `td` itself?

Comment: Post the HTML for the table. Also post what you've tried so far.

Comment: the select sits outside the table

Comment: So where is/are the checkbox(es) ?

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette  it's in the code I just posted...

Comment: Is `worksmart-select` the `id` of ALL checkboxes? (assuming there's many...)

Comment: @Haris, You said "select sits outside the table" , well you posted code where it seems select is the first column.(select wrapped in `<th>`).

Comment: <th>select is just the column header name. Not the actual <select> <option></option></select>

Comment: So what for the next row same column, would it have `<select>` ? Where you mentioned `x` and `o`

Comment: Post the rendered HTML for a checkbox. And tell us where it is in the table.

Comment: once a checkbox is select all the rest are disabled. I am looking to get the value of first td of the checked checkbox

Comment: ive showed that in the question, how the table looks @LouysPatriceBessette

Comment: *«once a checkbox is select»* doesn't make sense... What is the element tag name you are talking about ?

Comment: Checkbox, is different from a select tag, what are you confused about?

Comment: @Haris can you see if I'm on the right track or not with my answer,, if not, I'll delete it

Comment: I've updated the question

Comment: `<select>` is not a `checkbox`. Look here to know what a [checkbox](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_checked) is... And here for a [select](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select).

Comment: Look, read the question, you definitely do not understand what I am trying to ask @LouysPatriceBessette

Comment: And you definitely don't know what you're doing... And making us loose time. CLARIFY your question... And read this : [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette please read the question

Comment: You never replyed my question: *«Is worksmart-select the id of ALL checkboxes?»* 18 minutes ago... Or maybe you don't know what is an `id` too?

Comment: if you read the bloody question, I updated it to include the answer to your question man. jheez @LouysPatriceBessette but ill do it again, the ids are generated dynamically, and there are many checkboxes. the ids format is "worksmart-checkbox1", "worksmart-checkbox2" etc

Comment: It's about time! Answer the bloody questions if you want help.

Comment: lol dude u have anger issue @LouysPatriceBessette

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a CSS selector to find a single checked checkbox in a list, and from there locate the next `<td>` and grab its textContent.  You don't need the id attribute on the checkbox unless you were going to do something else with it.

```
$('#worksmart-select').on("change", function () {
    // find the checked checkbox
    var $chosen = $('td > input:checked');
    // we want the next td's content, so go up to our parent() node, then across to the next() td node, then grab its text
    var appId = $chosen.parent().next().text();
    // do something with appId
    console.log(appId);
});
```

Comment: this is exactly what I am after, could you explain this a bit? before I accept